# Show that the categories $G$-mod and $\mathbb{Z}G$-mod are equivalent.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I have another basic question inspired from reading the sixth chapter of Weibel's "An Introduction to Homological Algebra".

**First version of the question: a bit ambiguous**
At the first paragraph, there is written that the category of $G$-**mod** can be identified with the category of $\mathbb{Z}G$-**mod**, but the isomorphism is not so evident at my eyes. Please, could you help me in finding it?

A "corollary" of my main question, is the following another question.
Let consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ as a trivial $G$-module (yes, there is a connection with a previous question I asked here - [A clarification about the meaning of "Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be *the* trivial $G$-module".](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316080/a-clarification-about-the-meaning-of-let-mathbbz-be-the-trivial-g-modu)). Now, let's see $Z$ as a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module using the previous identification.

> Does $\mathbb{Z}$ become here a trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module?

**Second version of the question: let's be more precise!**
It seems that my question could be a bit ambiguous. Indeed we can interpret
the writing "$\mathbb{Z}G$-module" in two ways, because $\mathbb{Z}G$ is a group and a ring, and the consequently question "Does $\mathbb{Z}$ become here a trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module?" assumes two quite different meaning. Let me give the opportunity to clarify what I am searching for.

1. First interpretation. We can think at $\mathbb{Z}G$-**mod** as the category $G$-**mod** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-module) choosing as group $G= \mathbb{Z}G$. In this context, the two categories $G$-**mod** and $\mathbb{Z}G$-**mod** are equivalent as essentially shown by user D. Burde (thanks! :) ). Furthermore, the property "being a trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module" here means "to be an abelian group on which $\mathbb{Z}G$ acts trivially". Under this interpretation, my answer mean: if we consider $Z$ as $G$-module and then wee see it as a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module (and we can because the two categories are equivalent), does $Z$ continue to be a trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module? As explained still by D. Burde, the answer is **yes** and the problem is **solved**.
2. Because $\mathbb{Z}G$ is also a ring, we can consider the category $\mathbb{Z}G$-**mod** in the sense "an ordinary $R$-mod choosing as ring R=$\mathbb{Z}G$ (in this ordinary sense - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29 - just to avoid any kind of misunderstanding).
   Now, the books of Weibel claims that the two categories $G$-**mod** and  $\mathbb{Z}G$-**mod** are equivalent. I am sure Weibel refers to this kind of interpretation, because we want to use this fact to guarantee for the category $G$-**mod** the existence of enough projectives and injectives (a property true in every $R$-**mod** category). Consequently my *true* question is:

   > How can I find an equivalence between these two categories?

As in the previous "version" of the answer, a "corollay-question" is: let's consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a trivial $G$-**mod**, and then see $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$G-module (of course, second interpretation).

> How is defined the multiplication of $\mathbb{Z}G$ on $\mathbb{Z}$?

On a first time, I was expecting to find again a sort of "trivial module", but another post of mine ([What exactly is a trivial module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316867/what-exactly-is-a-trivial-module?lq=1)) seems to suggest something different.

Finally, please notice how essentially the entirely chapter 6 of Weibel's book (the treatment about Group (Co)homology) is "based" on the fact that $G$-**mod** has enough projectives/injectives, and to find the equivalence I am asking for should be the main way to prove this fact (as suggested by the author himself). Consequently, let me underline again how to understand this point is absolutely important from my point of view to feel safe every time I speak about projective resolutions in $G$-**mod** (just to say an example)  :-)

I hope you appreciate my effort to express my motivation, and of course thank you very much for any kind of helps!
Cheers

Comment: The categories are isomorphic, not just equivalent. This follows *immediately* from the universal property of group rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intended interpretation is absolutely that a $G$-module $M$ becomes a module over the *ring* $\mathbb{Z} G$. As a *group*, $\mathbb{Z} G$ is simply a free abelian group of the same rank as the order of $G$, so that structure remembers nothing about how $G$ acted on $M$.

As to the trivial $G$ module $\mathbb{Z}$, the action of $\mathbb{Z} G$ is $(a_1 g_1+...+a_ng_n) m=a_1(g_1m)+...+a_n(g_n m)=a_1m+...+a_nm=(a_1+...+a_n)m$. While this actuion is more or less trivial, one **does not** call $M$ a "trivial" $\mathbb{Z}G$ module. Wolfram Mathworld-an inconsistent resource at best-to the contrary, there is **no** action of an arbitrary ring on an arbitrary abelian group, so there is nothing deserving the general title of trivial module.

**EDIT** Looks like you still need a construction of the isomorphism between $G$ modules and $\mathbb{Z}G$ modules. Given $M\in G-\underline{Mod}$, define $M'\in \mathbb{Z}G-\underline{Mod}$ by the action $(\sum a_ig_i)m=\sum a_i(g_i m)$, where $\sum a_i g_i\in \mathbb{Z} G,m\in M, g_i$ acts on $m$ via the $G$-module structure, and $a_i$ acts on $g_im$ by repeated addition. In the other direction, given $N\in\mathbb{Z}G-\underline{Mod}$ define $N'\in G-\underline{Mod}$ by $gn=gn$, where on the right hand $g$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}G$ and on the left hand an element of $G$. I leave it to you to check $M'$ and $N'$ are modules with the given structures. Given a map $f:M_1\to N_1$ of $G$-modules, we get a map $f':M_1'\to N_1'$ of $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules by $f'(m)=f(m)$, and similarly in the other direction. It's obvious from the definition that these operations are mutually inverse, since I'm literally using the same functions on both sides, so this gives the desired isomorphism of categories.

Comment: Woow, that's perfect! Yes yes, of course that you a lot for the clarification! :-) It should completely solve my second answer, but unfortunately the first one (the equivalence between the two categories) remains open...do you have maybe some hints/reference for that?
Thank you! Cheers

Comment: OK, I thought Dietrich's answer should have satisfied there, but I gave a more detailed one. Note that I've actually done absolutely nothing, which is the usual case with isomorphisms (as opposed to equivalences) of categories. That is, the group ring module structure on a group module is just the combination of the group action and the canonical $\mathbb{Z}$-action on any abelian group.

Answer (score 5):

The identification is as follows. Let $M$ be a $G$-module. Then $M$ becomes a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module by
$$
\left( \sum_gn_g g\right)m=\sum_g n_g(gm).
$$
Conversely if $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, then $M$ becomes a $G$-module by
$$
gm=(1g)m.
$$
Since $R=\mathbb{Z}[G]$, viewed as a left $R$-module, is a projective object , $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-mod, and hence $G$-mod, is an abelian category with enough projectives.

Comment: Dear @DietrichBurde, may I ask again for a clarification, please?
I have just realized not to have a clear idea about the notion of trivial module. In a first moment, I was referring to the singleton with the only possible action, but I think to have done a big mistake. Then I tried to correct myself thinking to the group $\mathbb{Z}$ with the "trivial action", but another problem has risen: how can I have a trivial action on a non-zero module, and at the same time satisfy the axiom 2 stated, for example, by wikipedia? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29#Formal_definition)

Comment: Because I think not to have a clear idea about the general definition of a trivial module, I opened another post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316867/what-exactly-is-a-trivial-module Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Dear Prof. Burde,
now thinks begin to appear clearer. Please, could I ask you some clarification about your answer?
For sake of brevity, let's call [A] the first formula ("from G mod to ZG mod") and [B] the second one.
Just a preliminary remark: when I speak about "to be a ZG-module", I intendi "to be an ordinary $R$-module, with ZG as ring $R$". I need this meaning because in this way the equivalence between $G$-**mod** and ZG-**mod** ensure us that $G$-**mod** is abelian and has enough injectives and projectives (because it is true for any category of $R$-mod, $R$ ring).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, yes, I think I have understood *better* the maps that you suggests. But...unfortunately, they lead to a quite big problem by my point of view. In that way the trivial $G$-module $\mathbb{Z}$ seems *really* to become the trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, in the sense "the trivial $R$-module (ordinary definiton, the one - just to be sure, used for example in commutative algebra, with ring $R=\mathbb{Z}G$"). But according to the definition here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316867/what-exactly-is-a-trivial-module), it implies $\mathbb{Z}$=0!!!
What am I missing?

Comment: (I appreciate a lot your help: I have temporary deselected the button "accept answer" only because I strongly need to solve the problem suggested in my previous comment).

Comment: Oh no :-( I am sorry too, no no, let me explain better: you answer is almost complete and has only one detail that I am failing to understand, that is what I have written in my comment above. If you could try to fix this point...yes, I should be particularly grateful to you.
I bet it is nothing complicated: summing up my problem is:
 - if $\mathbb{Z}$ become a trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$ module, according to the definition here (same link that you indicated before https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316867/what-exactly-is-a-trivial-module) it must be 0.

Comment: Ops, I think I have misunderstood something crucial!!!
When you say "$\mathbb{Z}$ becomes the trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$ module", do you intend:
 (1) $\mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$-module *intending* it as a $G$-module with group $G=\mathbb{Z}G$ (in this case the explanation from user 113969 works);
 (2) $\mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial $R$-module, intending a ring module with $R = \mathbb{Z}G$? In this case the explanation of user113969 doesn't work, and we should have $\mathbb{Z}=0$ thanks what said by Berci.

Comment: I edited my question in order to be as more precise and clear as possible.
I hope you should be still interested in solving this problem!
Anyway, thanks for your suggestions and for your kindness.
Cheers

Comment: @DietrichBurde The problem here is that the MathWorld article is gibberish. The alleged module structure $ag=g$ is not a module structure unless $G$ is the trivial group or $R$ is the zero ring.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I thought, we are talking about $G$-modules ? There the alleged action $ag=a$ is called "trivial action", and this is a standard notion in group cohomology (see, e.g., [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjADahUKEwi-kJePj4LGAhWDhiwKHQFGAK4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww0.maths.ox.ac.uk%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Fcoursematerial%2F2014%2F3106%2F49%2Flecture14.pdf&ei=pJl2Vb6uHIONsgGBjIHwCg&usg=AFQjCNHebfUQna9QEROIFzZe609IGcX5Rw&bvm=bv.95039771,d.bGg)). For this $G$ need not be the trivial group.

Comment: I mean the alleged $R$-module structure, sorry! It looks like you removed your comment linking to the wrong Mathworld article, where they claimed there's a trivial $R$-module structure on every abelian group $M$, which is false. So all you can mean by trivial $\mathbb{Z}G$ module is one induced from a trivial $G$ module, which is confusing at best since the action of $\mathbb{Z}G$ does actually do something.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, you are right, I have confused $gm=m$ with $gm=g$.