# Physicists construct their potentials starting from the Laplace equation, why they do not use another differential operator, like theta Θ?

Tags: harmonic-functions, laplacian, jacobian

Mine is more a technical curiosity, because the $\text{Laplace operator}$ is one of the many differential operators from which we can start, we also have the $\text{Jacobi Theta}$  $\theta$ operator $\rightarrow$ also that is an elliptical function (also *Ramanuajan* generalization preserves its properties).

Why start from Laplace (homogeneous Poisson equation)?
What's so special and more than other differential operators for example compared to that of Jacobi?

For example, if I started from the $\text{Whittaker equation}$  or from the $\text{Bessel equations}$ (ordinary linear equations of the second order homogeneous) what changes for a physicist that deals with potentials and harmonic functions?

Comment: Inverse square law forces + forces are proportional to the gradient of the potential + 3 dimensional universe = Laplace/Poisson equations for the potential. The second thing is a relatively natural thing, if you think about it. The first and third are AFAIK just quirks of the universe being the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations that physicists use encode physical 'stuff' which is required to respect the symmetries of the universe. In simple models, we assume space is just $\mathbb R^n$ and the symmetrices are the Euclidean motions.

It turns out that one can describe explicitly *all* differential operators that are invariant under the Euclidean group. They have to be translation invariant, which is easy, and then invariant under the orthogonal group, which is a bit more complicated. It turns out that the Laplacian is the simplest invariant differential operator — the only one of order $2$.

Comment: mm..interesting, so to have not *non-translation-invariant* we shoudn't select *Euclidean group*, can you give me an example of non-invariant differential operator not under Euclidean group ? Is possible to integrate Laplacian equation with a non-invariant differential operator ?

Comment: I don't know hat a «non-invariant differential operator not under Euclidean group» means.  As for your second question, I have no idea what it means.

Comment: sorry, maybe I misunderstanding something, is possible describe a differential operators under Euclidean group like non-translation invariant ? I  try to find an operator that is not translation invariant like Laplace operator, I don't know if I need to follow something like [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103922131). I try to find a `non-invariant differential operator`, is possible to build it ? I try to see something like [this also](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960188903271)

Comment: There are no invariant differential operators of first order, so that gives you tons of examples of non-invariant operators.

Comment: Non-invariant operators on second order exist? I never heard for 2nd order . Just last thing related about translation invariant under Euclidean Groups - is also possible to generate a non-invariant operator using G-Modules ? There are some connections between translation invariants and [trivial action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316867/what-exactly-is-a-trivial-module) ?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: As I wrote, the laplacian is the only invariant differential operator (up to a scalar factor) so any other differential operator is non-invariant.

Comment: So Theta operator is `non-invariant`, and this is a first or second order ? Is possible to integrate a non-invariant operator into Laplace operator (only invariant operator) ? Is there a method to do that ?